# Find the roots of $z^6 + 3z^3 + 4 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Hello I have some issues solving:

Find all $z \in C$

$z^6 + 3z^3 + 4 = 0$

How do you solve this?

---

The solutions are:

1) $0.8721 \pm 0,9093i$

2) $0.3514 \pm 1.2099i$

3) $-1.2235 \pm 0.3006i$

Comment: Let $z^3=a$ and solve for $a$

Comment: That's what I did before but can't get further than this: $A^2 + 3A + 4 = 0$

Comment: The point behind Raptor's recommendation is that, if $y=z^3$, then the equation reduces to $y^2+3y+4=0$, which can then solve for $y$. Once you have two $y$ values, you take the three cube roots to get the values of $z$.

Comment: Use the fact that $ax^2+bx+c=0\implies x=\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ to obtain answers for $a$.

Comment: If you are studying the complex numbers, then you must have learnt the quadratic equations already.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have $x1=z^3= -1.5 + 1.322876i , x2= z^3= -1.5 - 1.322876i$. Now how do I know there are three solutions insteads of two?

Answer (score 1):

$$z^3=\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt{7}}{2}=-2e^{\pm i\theta},$$ with $\tan\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt 7}3$.

Then

$$z=-\sqrt[3]2\,e^{(\pm i\theta+2k\pi)/3}, k=0,1,2.$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know k = 0,1,2?

Comment: @ScoobyDuh: try other values...

Comment: How do you get $-2e^{±iθ}$? The forumle for $|z| = {\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}} = 2$ Where is the minus coming from?